# Why do web3 dApps need servers?

Tags: web3js, dapps, dapp-development

I see a lot of projects run into server capacity issues at launch (token sale, nft launch, etc). [[1]](https://twitter.com/doom_cats/status/1379893539283292166?s=20), [[2]](https://twitter.com/viniciusfbm/status/1378068848444850180)

What reason(s) would require these projects to have a server, versus deploying a static frontend to S3/Netlify? My understanding is that the "backend" is the blockchain, and transactions are sent client side with `web3.eth.sendTransaction()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's not fixed rule, but usually part of a dapp may work on-chain and part off-chain. While a static frontend with some js can satisfy the former, the latter may require additional resources (e.g. bandwith, database, mail services, ...).

...btw many projects are still hosting on cheap VPS instead of the cloud ;)

Comment: Ok cool, what exactly do you mean by bandwidth in this context? And I get external services like mail etc, but do those really require an application server? Can't they be a backend service (if the dApp really needs mail)?

And in what contexts do they need databases? I guess cacheing some data off the blockchain? I see a lot of dApps using the graph protocol which would be called client side?

Comment: Is there something with ethereum node(s) I may be missing? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Lots of questions... As you noticed there's plenty of choices to be made. Point is: every project has its own requirements (and budget). Going back to your initial question, just because you may have different answers to these questions you can't just make a generalization as "a simple static web3-enabled site with a blockchain backend" ;)
Different requirements, different architectures/services/...